# await method in task

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, task

I work on a document downloader in a  windows store app, and I have a problem with tasks.
So here is a sample of my code :

**Task created and started**

```
...
HttpDownloader httpDownloader = new HttpDownloader(server);

Action<object> action = (object doc ) => httpDownloader.DownloadDocument((Document)doc);

Task t1 = new Task(action,selection.doc);
t1.Start();
...
```

**DownloadDocument method**

```
...
FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
// Dropdown of file types the user can save the file as
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Application/pdf", new List<string>() { ".pdf" });
// Default file name if the user does not type one in or select a file to replace
savePicker.SuggestedFileName = doc.name+"_"+doc.version;

StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync(); // Here an exception is launch.
...
```

And every time I get :

> Element not found (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80070490)

Without task, my code works fine, but since I want to use tasks to manage the different download, I have this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Action` runs on a random pool thread, which is different from your main thread (as scheduled by `Task.Start`). There you access your `doc` object which, I assume, was created on the main thread. This might be the reason for the fault.

Generally, you should not access objects (especially UI elements) across differed threads, unless they are specifically designed to be thread-safe.

**EDITED**: You probably do not need a task here. Just do `await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync()` and mark your outer method as `async` (the method which currently creates the task).

To understand better what thread you're on, it may help to add a debug trace like this:

```
Debug.Print("<Method name>, Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
```

Comment: No, the object `doc` is not in involved in this error. It clearly comes from the call `await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync()`.

Comment: yes, it's works fine without task, with just asynchronous methods. But I was looking for a way to manage all this generated tasks in order to cancel them or display a list of them. Is there a way to access a default ThreadPool or TaskFactory and get control on current tasks ?

Comment: I can only tell that FileSavePicker is created and called on a thread different from your main UI thread. I'm not sure if it is designed for that, as there's no UI on its thread (like a parent form). In the code your posted, the only thing that your `DownloadDocument` action does is displaying the UI to let the user choose the file name. Next to that, does it actually save the file?
You would probably want a background task for an IO-bound action, not for a UI action.

Comment: I guess you want to manage the tasks which actually do the job on saving/uploading files, right?

Comment: I see what you mean. Maybe I should split my method in different parts. In this way, I could call the FileSavePicker in my main thread and then download the document in a task. I will have a look to the relation between thread and main UI thread.

Comment: Well I found how to solve. Just add a parameters to the start method : `t1.Start(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());`. And it's work perfectly but I don't really understand how it works. Thanks anyway for your help @Noseratio.

Comment: No problem :) However, I still think this may not be exactly what you want. Once you have specified `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`, the task will be queued for later execution on the same thread, via `SynchronizationContext.Post`, there will be NO background worker thread involved. You simply defer the task execution. A rough analogy would be like you would do it upon a timer event with 1ms timeout :)